# Defining domain in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

I am asked to define the domain for the following given that $z=x+iy$:

$a) \quad f(z) = \dfrac 1 {z^2 + 1}$

$b) \quad f(z) = \dfrac 1 {1 - |z|^2}$

How would this be different from a normal domain on reals and is drawing it out the only way to get the answer?

Comment: One does not need to draw a picture. In both cases you just have to avoid the division by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same problem as you did with real functions: division by zero is bad. So to find the domain, find where the denominator is not equal to zero.

Not that in **some contexts**, you'll consider the set $\mathbb{C}\cup{\{\tilde{\infty}\}}$, and you might encounter $\dfrac z 0 = \tilde{\infty}$ for $z \ne 0$. But I don't like that convention so I won't say any more.

Answer (score 0):

These functions are defined everywhere except at those points, where the denominator becomes 0. For the first function this is the case iff $z^2+1=0$, which is equivalent to $z=i$ or $z=-i$. For the second function this is the case when $1-|z|^2=0$, which is equivalent to $|z|=1$ (or, if you prefer using sets, $z\in\partial\mathbb D$).